# Calculating number of positive integer pairs satisfying xy<c

Tags: c++, optimization, matrix

Given c>0, I need to find out out how many positive integer pairs x,y satisfy xy< c.
One of approach is

```
int No_Of_Factors(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    int i,divisors=1,power;
    int N=sqrt(n);
    for(i=2;i<=N;i++)
     {
        power=0;
        while(n%i==0)
        {
            power++;
            n/=i;
        }
        divisors*=(power+1);
     }
     if(n>1)
      divisors*=2;
return divisors;
}
```

Calling the above function which calculates all factors of a number, for i=1 to c-1. For example, if c=17, I'll call the above function for i=1 to 16.
For i=16, function returns 5 as 16 can be written as 1* 16, 16*1, 2*8, 8*2, 4*4.
Is there any other way to approach this in a faster way?

Comment: Belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code that has no problem.

Comment: Yup, the code works fine but I want to know if there can be some other smarter approach, because the approach I've discussed is naive.

Comment: Yes, there is a smarter approach. You don't need to calculate any factors. Do you know how many integers x satisfy `1*x<17`? What about `2*x<17`? `3*x<17`? Can you sum these things up? If you need unordered pairs, how do you avoid counting same pairs twice?

Comment: @n.m. Your reply sounds worthy, it'll be great if you can please elaborate.

Comment: @nm I need ordered pairs

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: I don't believe so.  It's asking for a better way to accomplish a task, not for a code review.

Comment: @mah: Lots of valid questions are about working code without problems.

Comment: Should be moved to CodeReview.

Comment: @tmyklebu "valid" doesn't mean "on topic" (and hence, doesn't mean valid _here_), though you're right, there are a lot of questions that don't belong here that get posted by people that aren't familiar with what _is_ on topic here. There's a help page to tell people what is valid _here_ but people mostly don't think it'll tell them anything important. As others have noted, codereview, another stack exchange network site, is likely appropriate for this question.

Comment: @mah: But he's not asking for a code review.  He's asking about a software algorithm, and, according to the FAQ, that's on-topic.  (And none of the exceptions carved out by the FAQ for badly-asked questions apply.)

Comment: @math Yes, I'm not asking to review my approach or my program, I know it gives correct answers. I was interested in knowing if there's some other better approach to this problem (xy<c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone else pointed out, you can just compute sum(i=1..c-1) floor((c-1) / i).  However, there is a better approach.  Notice that either x <= sqrt(c-1) or y <= sqrt(c-1) or both.  Thus the following approach will also work:

```
int sc = sqrt(c-1);
int ans = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= sc; i++) ans += (c-1) / i;
return ans * 2 - sc * sc;
```

Here `ans` counts the number of ways to find x and y such that xy <= c-1 and x <= sqrt(c-1).  There are also `ans` ways to find x and y such that xy <= c-1 and y <= sqrt(c-1).  Adding these two together double-counts that ways to find x and y such that xy <= c-1, x <= sqrt(c-1), and y <= sqrt(c-1), so we subtract that number off.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something along the lines of

```
#include <math.h>

int calc_num_pairs(int c)
{
    float n = c-1;
    int num_pairs=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        num_pairs += floor(n / i);
    return num_pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

[image]

considering ordered pair and x>0, y>0. It is easy to derive:

- the first factor x should be >= 1 (by definition) and < (c-1)
- fixed the first factor to be x then you have floor((c-1) / n) factors

the function can be approximated asymptotically with: (c-1) * (gamma + log(c-1)) where gamma is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Answer (score 0):

You could determine this arithmetically.

If XY < C, then

```
1 <= x < C, Y = 1
2 <= x < C/2, Y = 2
. . .
```

Through a summation formula.